# How to Use asp.NetCore 2.0.0 on Visual Studio 2019

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, visual-studio-2019

I need to start a project with .Net Core 2.0.0 because of some problem of version with other projects but Visual Studio does not allow it, mainly because the .Net Core 2.0.0 option does not appear in the options and when creating a 2.1 project and change it to 2.0 I make mistakes of compatibility.

They told me that using the .Net Core 2.0 SDK I could create my project, but I have no idea how to install the SDK in Visual Studio or how to use it.
If you could help me with some information for that, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

You first need to ensure that you have that particular SDK installed. From the command-line you can run:

```
dotnet --list-sdks
```

If you don't see the version there, you'll need to install it from: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.0

I'm not sure if it will show up in Visual Studio as an option. It *should*, but it's also end-of-life so may not. Regardless, you can simply edit your csproj and change the `<TargetFramework>` node:

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
```

That said, you *really* should get off 2.0 to at least 2.1. The 2.0 release is end-of-life and unsupported. The 2.1 release is the current LTS (long-term support) version.

Answer (score 1):

Close Visual Studio and then download and install the .net core 2.0 SDK here: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.0

Use the dotnet-installer to install it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script

Please be aware that .net core 2 is no longer supported by Microsoft and it is recommended that you use .net core 2.1 or greater.

Comment: I have already downloaded SDK 2.0.0 and Runtime 2.0.0 the files are zip and still contain the libraries of net core 2.0 and later?

Comment: Should be an installer.

Comment: if i extract the zip contains one application "dotnet"

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script